# mouseover issue with animation duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Below is a simple `mouseover` and `mouseleave` function.

When the mouse is over the menu it will pop out from the left, when leave it will hide again.

The problem is that it work perfectly if the mouse enter `<ul id='reference'>` directly, but if I enter via its first li child, and then do a `mouseleave`, it will take a long time for it to hide. Please check the demo below to see what I mean (enter mouse via the little tab then `mouseleave`, vs enter mouse via the big box then `mouseleave`)

```js
$("#reference").on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: 0
  });
});
$("#reference").on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: -115
  });
});
```

```css
#reference{
  position: absolute;
  background-Color: white;
  box-Shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
  z-Index: 100000;
  list-Style: none;
  border-Radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-Bottom: 50px;
  min-Height: 300px;
  width: 120px;
  max-Width:120px;
  left: -115px;
}
#reference li:nth-child(1){
  position:relative;
  padding-top:25px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  left:30%;
  height:80px;
  width:25px; background:white;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px; float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="reference">
  <li>
    <i class='fa fa-user' style="position:relative; color:gray;"></i></li>
  <li>Welcome,</li>
  <li>Profile</li>
  <li><a>Log out</a></li>
  <li>empty</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cgvsbs9s/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as that, use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` ***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgvsbs9s/1/)***

[image: Difference between mouseenter and mouseover]

the reason is that `mouseover` is prone to event bubbling from child elements (triggering again the `mouseover` event). Since every child element triggered a new `mouseover` (with an *expand* animation which was not queue-cleared) resulted in: `expand 400ms * times every child triggered a mouseover` = an extended animation time the `#reference` should stay expanded.

**Example** showing the **difference** between `mouseover` and `mouseenter` events:

```js
var mouseover = 0, mouseout = 0, mouseenter = 0, mouseleave = 0;
$("#parent").on("mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
  $("#"+e.type).text(++window[e.type]);
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
#parent{
  padding: 12px;
  background: #0cf;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:40px;
}
.child{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: #f0c;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Mouseover <b id=mouseover>0</b> Mouseout <b id=mouseout>0</b></p>
<p>Mouseenter <b id=mouseenter>0</b> Mouseleave <b id=mouseleave>0</b></p>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Use those events always is this pair/combinations

> mouse**enter** / mouse**leave**
> mouse**over** / mouse**out**  // there's really rare occasions where you want to use this two guys

**But most importantly** don't forget that some users are fast with their mouse,
multiple hovers might end building up your animations, so you need to clear your animations queue (buildups) using `.stop()`

```
$("#reference").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(evt) {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    left: evt.type === 'mouseenter' ? 0 : -115
  });
});
```

***[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgvsbs9s/3/)***

#### The good news is you don't need JS at all

simply add this to your CSS:

```
#reference {
  /* other styles... */
  left: -115px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
}
#reference:hover{
  left: 0;
}
```

***[CSS-only jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgvsbs9s/4/)***

Comment: Awesome thanks! just curious is stop() basically the same as evt.stopPropagation()?

Comment: @user308553 no, use `.stop()` if the timing between two animations might end up clustered by a new animation; It prevents the animations to stack (clears the animation queue). i.e: one hovers fast 10 times your element he'll end up seeing all those 10 animations. `event.preventDefault()` is used mainly to prevent a default browser behavior such as i.e: you have an anchor, and in you want to prevent the browser to *follow*, another common example is a form `submit` if you use preventDefault() the browser will not follow any default *action* etc... So mostly related to browser defaults.

Comment: @user308553 take also a look at the CSS-only solution.

Comment: o yea! I never thought of that even thought I use hover all the time, thanks

Comment: @user308553 woops you asked me about `event.stopPropagation()`, this one is used if you want an event, i.e. a `click` on a child element to NOT propagate to the parent element. Inside DOM, events do propagate, that means that every click on any element, if not `event.stopPropagation()` will bubble up the DOM tree till `document.documentElement` is reached. If you have a parent element that has also a click event bound to it, you should use `stopPropagation` if you don't want a click on a child element to be registered by the parent element.

Comment: @user308553 play with this example to understand visually the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/7gtckkmh/

Comment: perfect! Thanks for all the examples and explanations, you are awesome! Really appreciate it